# How to make tooltip work with pointer-events none?

Tags: html, css

I want applied pointer-events:none; on question icon which is inside the label when i click on it. It should show tooltip on hover on question icon and also want to avoid hover on input field when click on this question mark class.

```html
<label style="pointer-events: none;" for="email_for_confirmation" class="form-label">
  Email Address 
  <span class="form-label-tooltip">
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i>
    <span class="tooltip-msg">We will send your order confirmation here.</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

I added this but it's not working accordingly.

Comment: <label style="pointer-events: none;" for="email_for_confirmation" class="form-label">Email Address <span class="form-label-tooltip"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i><span class="tooltip-msg">We will send your order confirmation here.</span></span></label>

Comment: Can anyone help for this?

Comment: Using `pointer-events:none` for this is definitely not the right approach. Think about what you're actually saying with that setting: "no pointer events".

Comment: then what will be the right approach?

Comment: Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for people who'd like to help.

Comment: `pointer-events: none` does exactly what the name states to do: It does not trigger any pointer event such as hover tooltips. The real question is why you need `point-events: none` in the first place.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve ? is this the entire scope of the code, do you want the user to be able to hover on the question mark and not the label?  or on the label and not the question mark ? or is the question mark in the way of something else ? , please elaborate , can you use JS in your scope ?